Bayesian time varying coefficient
While I am writing a thesis on how the cyclicality of fiscal policy evolves over time in certain countries using Bayesian time-varying regression, there are some questions that I would like to ask.

I know that Bayesian regression requires a prior distribution (which is chosen by the model maker), and I have no idea what the prior distribution should be. Should I use non-informative prior?
How does Bayesian time-varying regression really work? Is it similar to rolling window method in normal regression or is there another method where I can do time varying coefficient model in Bayesian regression?


Prior for what? Can your regression coefficient be positive and negative? Can it be outside the range $\pm 1$? Another way of looking at this is that priors allow you to constrain your solution space to avoid  unreasonable parameters. Also you can look at them as places where your optimizer begins the search for solution. So describe what parameters you want to set the priors for, and describe what you would expect these values to be or not to be. This is good practice even for frequentist approach - allows you to identify null/alertnative hypothesis

The assumption on prior, I am a bit confused about how these prior are set in running a Bayesian regression.

You might want to take a look at the walker package.

@Yohan, you need to describe what you are modelling. What are the individual coefficients in your model, what values could they take, possibly, and what values are not possible? For example, lets say you z-scaled all your quantities. This would mean that you are unlikely to see things vary by by more than 5 away from zero. This would mean that your regression coefficients have to be close to $\pm 1$ range.

Not an answer, but perhaps you benefit from having a peek at my tutorial. You can read most of it online under "Read Sample."
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0BTNVFR65
